# Selenium WeDriver C#: Not getting element locator of angular based application

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to get the locator of the input field. Attributes like id, name, text are not available. I get locator using xpath //*[@class='form-control validation-field ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched']   which doesn't seem to be the best practice.

```
 <input class="form-control validation-field ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" type="text" step="undefined" min="undefined" max="undefined">
```

I am trying to automate an angular based application using Selenium WebDriver C#.

```
<ng-component class="ng-star-inserted">
<form novalidate="" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched">
    <div class="form-group mb-0">
        <input class="form-control validation-field ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" type="text" step="undefined" min="undefined" max="undefined">
        <!----><small class="text-danger ng-star-inserted">Value is required</small>
        <!---->
        <!---->
    </div>
</form>
</ng-component>
```

Comment: And what does the code look like that doesn't work?

Comment: I need to get the locator of the input field. Attribute names like id, name, text are no available. The class name is also not uniwue

     <input class="form-control validation-field ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" type="text" step="undefined" min="undefined" max="undefined">

Comment: What is unique? Because that is your only problem.

Comment: I get locator using xpath //*[@class='form-control validation-field ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched']   which doesn't seem to be the best practise

Comment: well, if you have no other means to get to that element, xpath it is.